# Inversify Express order routes

Tags: node.js, express, router, inversifyjs

I'm using `inversify-express-utils` and I'm looking for a way to set an order for how my endpoints are matched.

eg... using express. The router could have

```
router.get('/users/me')
router.get('/users/:userId')
```

and the `users/me` endpoint would resolve successfully.

But using `inversify`, I have endpoints and controllers like so (detail left out just to show decorators)

```
@controller('/users')
   @httpGet('/:userId')
```

```
@controller('/users/me')
   @httpGet('/')
```

It seems like the `users/me` controller is being registered later, even though I import it earlier, and so it's calling `users/:userId` with the `userId` param set to me instead.

Is there a way to sort this?

Answer (score -1):

with regex  conditions

```
router.get('users/:userId(^me$)', (req, res) => {

      res.send('it is me')
  });

router.get('users/:userId)', (req, res) => {

      res.send('it is not me')
  });
```

Comment: No... that's still using express's native route registration which works fine without this funky workaround

Comment: Updated my question to be clearer... the point is that we're using this package (https://github.com/inversify/inversify-express-utils) specifically to register endpoints, not express's native express.Router